# Chromium build failed (Windows 10)

Tags: build, chromium

Good afternoon. Tell me who build Chromium om Windows. It is required to brand Chromium (start page, bookmarks, tray icons, name), collect according to the instructions at the site chromium. When assembling through VS 2015, the following error list appears. The assembly takes place on the server, 64 GB RAM, Intel Xeon.

1. The compilation goes to 60-70%, after which VS crashes, restarts and gives an error: "The following files can not be found - all.sln - so they will not be loaded" - after this error the assembly stops, I tried 10 times already.
2. Ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. Warning: premature end of file; Recovering
3. FAILED: obj / third_party / yasm / yasm_utils / xmalloc.obj

Answer (score 0):

First, try running the build from command line:

```
ninja -C src/out/Default
```

If it still fails, make sure you carefully followed prerequisites installation instructions. Specifically, try `gclient sync -f` and make sure it finished normally before building.